# How to best store intermediate state for constraint scoring

Tags: optaplanner

I am currently working on a problem in Optaplanner involving an overconstrained meetings problem in a timegrain pattern. The problem involves 1500 timegrains, endless meetings of varying lengths, 40 rooms, and 50 meeting leaders - all with thier own personal timegrains. I plan for around two weeks ahead and try to find the best meetings to schedule based on several constraints.

The only planning entity an "assigment" that couples meetings, to persons, to time, to rooms.

The issue is that I need to reward/penalize if any of the 50 persons end up with idle time grains. I am considering two options:

1. For each person: Traverse all 1500 time grains and all scheduled meeting, crosscheck if they collide with one timegrain at a time, to see which was used and which are left idle, which would be a big task in O(N²).
2. Store some intermediate state by marking each timegrain continuously as meetings are scheduled using a variableListener to set whether a timegrain is referred by sheduled meeting, and then traverse the timegrains themselves to see how many were never used in O(n) time.

However, Optaplanner documentation states that altering facts such as timegrains during solving is a bad strategy. So, I am wondering if there is a better strategy or a third option to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modelling flexible timelines is notoriously difficult. So far the best idea we've had is to write a custom `ConstraintCollector` which orders events in sequence and has the capability to track breaks between them.

An example of one such collector can be found [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/score/NurseRosteringConstraintProvider.java#L130). The constraint takes all shifts, puts them on a single timeline, groups them into sequences separated by breaks. Once the data is pre-processed like this, it becomes relatively easy to penalize/reward the blocks.

Some caveats:

- This is a complex calculation. As such, it is slow.
- The experimental constraint collector is not shipped out of the box. You should not depend on `optaplanner-examples`. You should copy-paste it into your own code, and adapt it any way you see fit.
- It is a complex piece of code, and probably requires much more testing and documentation than it currently has. Again, we offer it as an example, not as a ready-made solution.

Comment: Thx, that seems very usable but will need to study the " ExperimentalConstraintCollectors.consecutive()" it a bit to incorporate that method. I  also get then that your idea is a more complex variant of suggestion 1  and that my suggestion 2 should not be pursued further.

Comment: I'd argue it's a mix of 1 and 2. It processes the entire solution, that's the part from 1. It doesn't use variable listeners, but it happens continuously; that's the part from 2. And because it is a constraint collector, it happens incrementally, hopefully reducing the O(n^2) to something more manageable.